# How do I figure out the best path for admin certification?

Tags: certification, admin, learning, path

I'm new to the forum, a longtime casual Salesforce user and I would like to become an admin.

I started with "Prepare for Your Salesforce Administrator Credential" in Trailblazer-

However, I have since found "Build Your Admin Career" and wonder if I need to take it , or do I need both and am I missing anything else? I have stared taking it as well and it seems like some of this would be preliminary to the first curriculum.

So I'm not entirely sure where to turn and don't want to miss a step. Is there a clear explanation as to best practices to prepare for admin certification? Or anyone who's been here a while that can provide some direction?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on starting your Salesforce cert journey.

I would start with the Trailmix that you reference [Prepare for Your Salesforce Administrator Credential](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/users/strailhead/trailmixes/prepare-for-your-salesforce-administrator-credential). This will give you a good overview of the information that needs to be learned to earn the cert.

I would also check out these links for more information about what will be on the exam.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Salesforce-Certified-Administrator-Exam-Guide
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/credentials/administrator

There are also 3rd party resources that can offer more practice exams and I have found these helpful in order to prepare myself for the exams. These are mostly paid options but can be helpful. I have found Focus on Force to be a good resource. These are by no means required though.

Good luck on your journey!

Comment: Thank you very much!